# Mobile App still showing old icon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The icon for M&TV on the mobile app (I can only speak for Android) is still the old icon.

Is this another cache related issue, or will this require a future update to the app itself to correct?

Not a *huge* deal, but I wanted to point it out in case this was an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will eventually fall out of cache and pull a new icon.  We cache things like this heavily to ensure we don't abuse your data plan.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the reply!